# Disable all dates not first of month or week

Tags: java, javafx, datepicker

I'm using a datepicker object and having some trouble trying to disable specific days of the month.

I'd like to be able to disable every date except the first of the month, and on another datepicker I'd like to be able to disable all days except the first day of every week (monday), how is this done?

Comment: You could have a picker which just allows the user to select the month/week, and then specify the day yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize the DatePicker by using the `DatePicker.setDayCellFactory` method. In order to disable some days you could do something like:

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalDate;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.DateCell;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;
public class DatePickerDemo extends Application {
     // Factory to create Cell of DatePicker
    private Callback<DatePicker, DateCell> disableMonday() { 
        final Callback<DatePicker, DateCell> dayCellFactory = (final DatePicker datePicker) -> new DateCell() { 
            @Override
            public void updateItem(LocalDate item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);                
                // Disable Monday
                if (item.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.MONDAY) {
                    setDisable(true);
                    setStyle("-fx-background-color: #ffc0cb;");
                }
            }
        };
        return dayCellFactory;
    }

    private Callback<DatePicker, DateCell> disableNotFirstOfMonth() { 
        final Callback<DatePicker, DateCell> dayCellFactory = (final DatePicker datePicker) -> new DateCell() { 
            @Override
            public void updateItem(LocalDate item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);                
                // Disable all except first of month
                if (item.getDayOfMonth() != 1) {
                    setDisable(true);
                    setStyle("-fx-background-color: #ffc0cb;");
                }
            }
        };
        return dayCellFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker();
        datePicker.setValue(LocalDate.now());
        datePicker.setShowWeekNumbers(true);

        DatePicker datePicker2 = new DatePicker();
        datePicker2.setValue(LocalDate.now());
        datePicker2.setShowWeekNumbers(true);

        Callback<DatePicker, DateCell> dayCellFactory  = this.disableMonday();
        Callback<DatePicker, DateCell> dayCellFactory2 = this.disableNotFirstOfMonth();
        datePicker.setDayCellFactory(dayCellFactory);
        datePicker2.setDayCellFactory(dayCellFactory2); 

        FlowPane root = new FlowPane();
        root.getChildren().add(datePicker);
        root.getChildren().add(datePicker2);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(20));

        stage.setTitle("DatePicker Demo");
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 200);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    } 
}
```

Comment: yeah but that doesn't stop me from entering the disabled date manually. Perhaps you could add some sort of validation to the textfield also.